# Command line error in OpenSUSE (old version)

Tags: linux, opensuse, zypper

I'm using an old version of OpenSUSE and when I try to update some package via the command line, e.g.

```
Zypper update firefox
```

it shows the message listed below.

> System management is locked by the application with pid 2181(/usr/sbin/packagekitd).
>   Close this application before trying again.

Comment: Try using root privileges (`su` or `sudo`)

Comment: Already tried Sudo ,but inspite of root previliges it's showing the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a `Zypper` instance running, that's what the error message is telling you. Just kill the other process and try again:

```
sudo kill 2181
```

If that doesn't work try

```
sudo kill -9 2181
```